# How to overwrite specific bytes in dump file in C#

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, binary, mysql

i'm having a mysql dump with some special characters ("Ä, ä, Ö, ö, Ü, ü, ß"). I have to reimport this dump into the latest mysql version. This is crashing the special characters because of the encoding. The dump is not encoded with UTF-8.

Within this dump there are also some binary attachments which should not be overwritten. Otherwise the attachments will be broken.

I have to overwrite every special character with the bytes that are readable for UTF-8.

I'm currently trying it that way (this is changing the ANSI ü to an for UTF-8 readable ü):

```
newByteArray[y] = 195;
if (bytesFromLine[i] == 252)
{
   newByteArray[y + 1] = 188;
}

newByteArray[y + 2] = bytesFromLine[y + 1];
```

> 252 is displaying a 'ü' in Encoding.Default. 195 188 is displaying a 'ü' in Encoding.UTF8.

Now i need help with searching this specific characters in this dump file an overwriting this bytes with the right bytes. I can't replace all '252' with '195 188' because the attachments would get broken then.

Thanks in advance.

Relax

Comment: can't you get mysql dump in utf8?

Comment: @MaxwellTroyMiltonKing this is not possible otherwise i would already be ready

Comment: Have you tried the `--default-character-set` argument on the command line importer? Ensure this matches the dump file's encoding (you should be able to get this from it's header if you open it in a text editor).

Comment: @DaveR. yes i already tried that. The import works well only the special characters are broken after import.

Comment: :) fair enough. obviously! What about other way round? Get new mysql dump use the old encoding? I just think there must be something in mysqldump to sort this out. Otherwise is it easy to distinguish between binary and other inserts? quite a fiddle

Comment: @MaxwellTroyMiltonKing The problem is my instructor gave me this dump and he told me this is the only dump he can give me. No other encoding or way possible..

Comment: So you basically have to go through the file, find the strings and fix encoding?

Comment: @MaxwellTroyMiltonKing you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **DISCLAIMER:** This might corrupt your data. The best way of dealing with this is to get a proper mysqldump from the source database. This solution should only be use when you don't have that option and stuck with a potentially broken dump file.

Assuming all strings in the dump file in quotes (using single quote `'`) and can be escaped as `\'`:

```
INSERT INTO `some_table` VALUES (123, 'this is a string', ...
```

Not too sure how binary data is represented. That might need more checks, you need to check your dump file and see if these assumptions are correct.

```
const char quote = '\'';
const char escape = '\\';

using (var dumpOut = new FileStream("dump_out.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
using (var dumpIn = new FileStream("dump_in.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    bool inquotes = false;
    byte previousByte = 0;
    var stringBytes = new List<byte>();
    while (true)
    {
        int readByte = dumpIn.ReadByte();
        if (readByte == -1) break;

        var b = (byte) readByte;

        if (b == quote && previousByte != escape)
        {
            if (inquotes) // closing quote
            {
                var buffer = stringBytes.ToArray();
                stringBytes.Clear();

                byte[] converted = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, buffer);

                dumpOut.Write(converted, 0, converted.Length);
                dumpOut.WriteByte(b);
            }
            else // opening quote
            {
                dumpOut.WriteByte(b);
            }

            inquotes = !inquotes;
            continue;
        }

        previousByte = b;

        if (inquotes)
            stringBytes.Add(b);
        else
            dumpOut.WriteByte(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: am i wrong or is this converting all text in this dump to utf8? And what is quote and escape for?

Comment: Yes. only converting the strings in quotes. Not sure about the binary data though - which might be represented using the same quotes, in which case you will need more checks.

Comment: something got broken.. MySQL: #1046 - No database selected

Comment: That sounds like a missing mysql option http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_database

Comment: The dump created by your code is missing the last 2 characters ( ");" ), why is it?